# Is this json format correct?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I have a json data when i'm trying to parse it returns error incorrect syntax please help me found the syntax error.

```
[{"isData":"Yes","Details":"[{"Id":"70","Name":"Test","FileName":"Uploaded","FileFormat":".mp4","FileType":"Video","FileDuration":"00:30:00  ","StartTime":"/Date(1372617000000)/","EndTime":"/Date(1372681771000)/","File":"2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4"}]"}]
```

And this is the class that is used to serialize data, i am using javascript serializer

```
public enum Data
{
    Yes,
    No
}

public class MessageResponse()
{
    public string isData { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
} 


      List<MessageResponse> response = new List<MessageResponse>();
string strJson="[{"Id":"70","Name":"Test","FileName":"Uploaded","FileFormat":".mp4","FileType":"Video","FileDuration":"00:30:00  ","StartTime":"/Date(1372617000000)/","EndTime":"/Date(1372681771000)/","File":"2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4"}]";
 var newData = new MessageResponse
                            {
                                isData = Data.Yes.ToString(),
                                Details = strJson
                            };

                            response.Add(newData);

            var jsonSerialiser1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           string result = jsonSerialiser1.Serialize(response);
```

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The syntax error is here: `"[{"Id`.

Answer (score 2):

That's invalid JSON. The `Details` property is incorrectly formatted. You should remove the quotes around the value. It should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "isData": "Yes",
        "Details": [
            {
                "Id": "70",
                "Name": "Test",
                "FileName": "Uploaded",
                "FileFormat": ".mp4",
                "FileType": "Video",
                "FileDuration": "00:30:00  ",
                "StartTime": "/Date(1372617000000)/",
                "EndTime": "/Date(1372681771000)/",
                "File": "2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

or if you want Details to be a string property (representing JSON), which is kinda lame, you should properly escape the double quotes:

```
[
    {
        "isData": "Yes",
        "Details": "[{\"Id\":\"70\",\"Name\":\"Test\",\"FileName\":\"Uploaded\",\"FileFormat\":\".mp4\",\"FileType\":\"Video\",\"FileDuration\":\"00: 30: 00\",\"StartTime\":\"/Date(1372617000000)/\",\"EndTime\":\"/Date(1372681771000)/\",\"File\":\"2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4\"}]"
    }
]
```

This structure you will be able to map to your current object model. But I would recommend you using the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the " from the details data:

```
[{
    "isData":"Yes",
    "Details":
    [{
        "Id":"70",
        "Name":"Test",
        "FileName":"Uploaded",
        "FileFormat":".mp4",
        "FileType":"Video",
        "FileDuration":"00:30:00",
        "StartTime":"/Date(1372617000000)/",
        "EndTime":"/Date(1372681771000)/",
        "File":"2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Details should be of type class (i.e. user defined class) and it should hold all the properties.

```
public class Details
{ public int Id {get; set;} ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your json is invalid.

It should not have the `"` before and after the `[` `]`

```
[
    {
        "isData": "Yes",
        "Details": [
            {
                "Id": "70",
                "Name": "Test",
                "FileName": "Uploaded",
                "FileFormat": ".mp4",
                "FileType": "Video",
                "FileDuration": "00: 30: 00",
                "StartTime": "/Date(1372617000000)/",
                "EndTime": "/Date(1372681771000)/",
                "File": "2562013172331815635077778118152815.mp4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Secondly, your class could be improved to be:

```
public class MessageResponse
{
    public string isData { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
} 

public class Details
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileFormat { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileDuration { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

You would probably want to set up the correct data types though for things like Start Time etc...